# How can output be directed to specific coordinates in the linux terminal?

Tags: c, linux, output

To be more specific, I am looking for an equivalent to the Windows API function: WriteConsoleOutputCharacter.  I know this style of direct output is possible, as I have seen the behaviour used before in the time that I have used Linux.  However, I am still a baby when it comes to Linux specific C libraries, and have not been able to ascertain any clues as to where I may find such functionality.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: you could look into the curses library for CLI manipulation

Comment: Perhaps [GNU readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) might be enough for you. Otherwise use [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) library.

It allows you to create some text-based UI in terminal. It is more than you asked, but if you need more than only this one function it may be best option for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ANSI control sequence](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/ansi_escapes.html)

Say, following will print 'ddd' string 3 lines above the prompt in bash

```
echo -e "\e[3Addd"
```

Answer (score -1):

This line will put a clock in right upper conner of a terminal (from commandlinefu.com)

```
while sleep 1;do tput sc;tput cup 0 $(($(tput cols)-29));date;tput rc;done
```